# What's the equivalent of GLSL's uintBitsToFloat and floatBitsToUint in Metal shading language?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, metal

I'm converting a compute shader from GLSL to Metal shading language. I'm using functions `uintBitsToFloat` and `floatBitsToUint` to store atomic variables. What's their equivalent in Metal? Example usage in GLSL:

```
shared uint ldsZMin;
...
float depth = -imageLoad( depthTexture, ivec2( globalThreadIdx.x, globalThreadIdx.y ) ).x;
uint z = floatBitsToUint( depth );
atomicMin( ldsZMin, z );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you can use an `as_type<type-id>()` cast for this.

From the very bottom of this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Metal/Reference/MetalShadingLanguageGuide/data-types/data-types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014364-CH2-SW1

> The Metal shading language adds an as_type operator to allow any scalar or vector data type (that is not a pointer) to be reinterpreted as another scalar or vector data type of the same size. **The bits in the operand are returned directly without modification as the new type.** The usual type promotion for function arguments is not performed.

```
float f = 1.0f;
// Legal. Contains: 0x3f800000
uint u = as_type<uint>(f);

// Legal. Contains:
// (int4)(0x3f800000, 0x40000000,
//        0x40400000, 0x40800000)
float4 f = float4(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);
int4 i = as_type<int4>(f);
```